# Why does global variable stay undefined even after assigning value to it in a local scope in javascript

Tags: javascript

My understanding of the closure property is that every variable inside in a function scope has access to all the variables in the parent scope(s) the function is in,

So considering this definition I don't understand the behavior of my code below:

```
var mouseX, mouseY;

window.onload = function() {

    this.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
        mouseX = event.clientX;
        mouseY = event.clientY
    }); // mouseX and mouseY are defined

    petObj = new Pets();


   }

function Pets(){
document.getElementById('imageList').addEventListener('mouseenter',function()
                                       {
                                       console.log(mouseX)} //undefined mouse X!!!
                                       }
```

I accept the assignation  of mouseX inside the anonymous function for mousemove event listener to reference the global variable declared outside the function. But as you can see it stays undefined outside the scope of the anonymous function

Comment: If you could explain why you think that `console.log()` call should print out a mouse coordinate value, it might help somebody provide a better explanation for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the name of my variable from mouseX to mouseXX and it works,not sure why it worked ,maybe the jquery namespace was messing with the variable name

Answer (score 6):

You're logging the value of "mouseX" inside the "load" handler that sets up the event handler. No events have happened yet, so the variable is still `undefined`.

The variables *are* available, and if you put a `console.log()` call inside the event handler, or somewhere else such that the code will run *after* some "mousemove" events have happened, you'll see the values being updated.

Comment: I check it inside pet object too, it still appears to be undefined there too :(,thanks for pointing out that should had taken care of that before asking

Comment: @Snedden27 it will be undefined until the point in time at which a "mousemove" event is successfully handled.

Comment: I do handle the mouse move event , and assign it but mouseX still stay undefined inside pets() function